# Use git for two branch

Tags: php, git, netbeans

think I am going to use these three files in Master Branch

**MASTER :**

```
index.php

  <b>hello</b>

test.php
img.jpeg
```

now I create a branch from Master

**NewBranch :**

```
index.php

     <b>hello</b>

test.php
img.jpeg
```

and now I will edit Master index.php file, and I will add two lines of code to master branch

**MASTER :**

```
index.php

  <b>hello</b>
  <a>test</a>
  <p>good</p>
```

and I will change some code in NewBranch

**NewBranch :**

```
index.php

     <b>hello</b>
     <div>this is new branch line</div>
```

I want to update NewBranch so I will have my own edited lines on New Branch and also updated lines on Master Branch

**NewBranch : (should be like as below)**

```
index.php

     <b>hello</b>
     <div>this is new branch line</div>
     <a>test</a>
     <p>good</p>
```

How can I achieve that? I have used netbeans Pull and Fetch, but did not worked. I also do not want to use git submodule ( as I do not have separate folder )

Comment: So you want to merge your master branch to your new branch, while keeping the master branch as is?

Comment: yes, I am going to merge two branches, but when I using netbeans pull ( as it merge ) , it show me > A merge commit is needed to synchronze current branch with orogon/master

Do you want to Merge current branch with origin/master or Rebase it onto origin/master?

Merge Rebase Cancel

Comment: and when I click on merge, it do not merge new lines

Comment: @Ata: Does it go itno conflict resolution phase? (Your example will give rise to merge conflicts)

Comment: No, It does not show any confilct

Answer (score 0):

1. You changes on both the branches should be "committed". Only changing will do no good.
2. Then you can rebase your NewBranch over master (`git rebase master NewBranch`)
3. Now you new branch has changes of itself and that of master. But master will have only its changes.

For more details on rebase please refer [this](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).

Comment: when I use Rebase, ( while I expected merge is enough for my work),  I will not able to commit my NewBranch Any More.

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps (assuming that you are using gitBash):

```
git checkout newbranch
```

do the changes for newbranch
    git commit -a -m "Your message"

```
git checkout master
```

do the changes for master

```
git commit -a -m "Your message"
```

now merging

```
git checkout newbranch
git merge master
git push
git checkout master
git merge newbranch
git push
gitk //you should see that both are at the same level in the git tree
```